RES What is minimum size for pregnancy in Red Eared Sliders and if they were egg-bound, is it always mortal?
I was gifted 2 RES after being with a family for 14+ years. I belive they have stunted growth (their shells are about 4 & 6 inches long across the top- not including the curvature) as they were both in a 10 gallon tank all these years and possibly underfed. Based on their front claws being exactly like their back ones,  I've determined they're both female. I believe they might possibly be pregnant as I felt the area and their hind legs and between their tails and it feels hard to me, but I don't know what it should feel like other than I read it's supposed to be soft. Also they seem too small, since I read it's not about age, but rather size. So I have many doubts, but I'm worried and want to do what I can to make them comfortable and happy. Today is Sept 1. Mating season is April - Auguust... Is it too late to try to get them to lay the eggs?  If pregnant and end up egg bound,  how soon could they die/ show symptoms of illness?
